# How to use MS Exchange SOAP API with Node.js?

Tags: xml, node.js, api, soap

I want to perform CRUD operations on the events, mails, calendars of an MS exchange account using Node.js, im using the npm module 'soap-ntlm-2',
https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap-ntlm-2. 
I have receive a response from the client after providing the url and username and password. The code used is the one in the link of the npm module,

```
var url = "http://server/instance/ReportService2010.asmx";
var options = {
wsdl_options: {
    ntlm: true,
    username: "RSUser",
    password: "Reporting2012",
    workstation: "",
    domain: ""
}
};

soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client, body) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
// normal use 
   //client.setSecurity(new soap.NtlmSecurity(options.wsdl_options.userName,          options.wsdl_options.password, options.wsdl_options.domain,      options.wsdl_options.workstation)); 
    // or object can be passed 
    client.setSecurity(new soap.NtlmSecurity(options.wsdl_options));

    console.log(client.describe());
    report = client.ReportingService2010.ReportingService2010Soap;
});
```

I have the response object in 'client', the 'body' parameter in the response is an empty object. In the docs that i have consulted ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj162981(v=office.15).aspx), it is written that in the request we need to send XML and XML will be received in the response. How to send XML with the request to the server using this module? Is there a better way or module to do this? Are there any better resources to learn how to perform CRUD operation on the Exchange account using the API?